# Randomly Short Continous Beeps with ASUS motherboard

Tags: motherboard

I have upgraded my PC and bought some components, after upgrading I installed both Ubuntu and Windows on my PC, but sometimes my PC completely freezes and sometimes it freezes and motherboard beeps. I have no idea what this type of problem come from. Maybe my power is not sufficient, but how can I assure?
Here is my PC specifications:

Motherboard: ASUS P8

Video Card: GTX 1060

CPU: Core i5 2500k

Hard Drive: HDD (1TB, 7.2K), 128Gb SSD

Power: Green 635 Watt

RAM: 16GB DDR3 HyperX

Comment: Beeps are the primary method mainboards use for communicating errors states, and these beeps are documented in the mainboard documentation. So, find the manuals for your mainboard and look for information about the beep codes or "POST Codes" as they are often called. https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1029959/

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my problem is solved by connecting my SSD to SATA III on the motherboard.